# Type error when trying to initialize app in angular firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

My imports App.module.ts

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {AngularFireDatabaseModule} from '@angular/fire/database';
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";
```

Declaration in App.module.ts

```
AngularFireAuthModule,
AngularFireDatabaseModule,
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase) <== Throws error
```

Environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
production: false,
firebase: {
apiKey: "AIzaSyC2QSffoNhgREPNol5GJSTwmnxDLgGzYLg",
authDomain: "shop-565e7.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://shop-565e7.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "shop-565e7",
storageBucket: "shop-565e7.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "207456264673",
appId: "1:207456264673:web:2579fc837258b4f3fc72a0",
measurementId: "G-HRBGNLXP8F"
}
};
```

Environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
production: true,
firebase: {
 apiKey: "AIzaSyC2QSffoNhgREPNol5GJSTwmnxDLgGzYLg",
authDomain: "shop-565e7.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://shop-565e7.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "shop-565e7",
storageBucket: "shop-565e7.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "207456264673",
appId: "1:207456264673:web:2579fc837258b4f3fc72a0",
measurementId: "G-HRBGNLXP8F"
}
};
```

**ERROR:**

> ```
> Type '{ ngModule: typeof AngularFireModule; providers: { provide:
> InjectionToken<string | FirebaseAppConfig>; useValue: string | 
> FirebaseAppConfig; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any>'.
>
> Type '{ ngModule: typeof AngularFireModule; providers: { provide:
> InjectionToken<string | FirebaseAppConfig>; useValue: string | 
> FirebaseAppConfig; }[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 
> 'Type<any>': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 5 more.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Please try using providers

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES),
    SharedModule,
    AngularFireModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    HomeModule,
    ArtiklarModule,
    MaskinerModule,
    StallbladModule,
    DialogsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: FirebaseOptionsToken, useValue: environment.firebase }
  ],
  exports: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

for more info https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1635